# How can I stop App Insights spamming the debugger with messages?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When I run my project locally under the debugger, App Insights sends a lot of messages to the debugger and clogs up my Output window. How can I stop this anti-social behavior without disabling AI completely?

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.Applicat...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to stop showing AI tracing messages in output window of visual studio, unfortunately, it's impossible. As of now, you can only disable AI completely to stop this behavior.

There is already [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/310) tracking this, but this feature is still in progress.